# Locking My Own Perl Script

Tags: perl

How can I lock my Perl script, list I have to do

1. Prevent Others from read or write Perl Script.
2. They should have only Permission to  Executing the Perl script.

Comment: And if you want to ship your code to a customer who should not see the source, forget about it. The best way to do that is a licence agreement.

Comment: @PerlDuck, hum... That's about making a file appear different based on who reads it. I don't see how that's in the least bit related.

Comment: Neither the linked question nor its answer deals with making the script unreadable. It touches making data used by the script unreadable, but that's not useful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on your operating system, which you haven't specified.

Typically, this is not possible.

On a UNIX based system (such as Linux or Mac OS) there are three permissions that can be given to users, groups and everyone: Read, Write, and Execute.

You can remove Write permission easily enough, but Read permission is required to allow the script to be executed.

(I assume you would experience a similar problem on Windows).

---

The only work around I can think of would be to rewrite the script as a webservice. Then the HTTP server would need to be able to read it, but the users themselves would not.

Comment: Re "*The only work around  I can think of would be to rewrite the script as a webservice.*", Or more generically, have the script run by a different user than the one that shouldn't be able to read the script. That could be a web service, but it could also be via impersonation (`sudo`), etc.

Answer (score 1):

If the system at hand is Linux/Unix and you have administrative access then you can use `sudo`.

With the following line in `/etc/sudoers`, anyone would be able to run, as *author1*, any executable file in the `public_bin` folder:

```
ALL  ALL = (author1) /home/author1/public_bin/*
```

However, take a look at `man sudoers` to understand implications wrt. environment and command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

755 is the *nix permission you'll need. This will give the owner full access and other read and execute.

As other has said, there is no way to make your code unreadable. However,can you obfuscate you code so only a reasonably good programmer could decode it. There are online tools, if you search "perl obfuscate" on bing you'll get some good results; these tools will mean no module is required. Or my personal favorite is the module Acme::Bleach.